# Comparing nullable and non-nullable properties on a join (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to join to tables on a column/property where it is nullable in one table and non-nullable in the other one

```
var x = from tr in testResults
        join u in Users
        on new { tr.SiteId, tr.UserId.Value } equals new { u.SiteId, u.UserId }                     
        into results
        from r in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select tr);
```

UserId is nullable in testResults and non-nullable in Users. I run into "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'". Anyone has a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps use a default value for the nullable one eg `tr.UserId ?? 0` which will use 0 if tr.UserId is null.

Comment: Did you try `tr.UserId` and `(int?)u.UserId`?  I'm not sure if linq-to-sql will like that or not.

Comment: @juharr I tried that it linq won't let you put a cast in a join clause.

Comment: i know nullable types are slower. but if its not a problem why dont you make UserId of Users nullable too?

Comment: Is it possible that `tr.UserId.Value` is a different type than `u.UserId`? Maybe `.Value` converts it to a `string`.

Comment: tr.UserId.GetValueOrDefault(0) seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Using lambdas with linq I find a lot easier and more powerful.